# What motors would work best for a 360 degree rotational platform?

Tags: motors, power-electronics

I'm trying to build a 6 DOF 360 degree platform and I need 3 powerful motors to rotate 3 arms that hold the center platform. The Pitch arm is the first arm, which will be doing most of the heavy lifting, then there's the roll arm, which could be less powerful, and finally the yaw arm which can be the least powerful, but all motors need to be able to provide torque at a moment's notice and be able to do so bi-directionally since the system will be used to simulate a fighter jet. The platform would be somewhere around 100 kg, which includes the weight for one person and some equipment: screen, joystick, etc. I'm not sure how heavy the arm's would be at the moment.

I don't have too much information on motors and such since I'm primarily a software developer. Help appreciated please.

Comment: Additionally, I think I'd need either a geared motor a separate gear system for the motor because from what I've been told, I'll need a gear box to be able to create the necessary torque to rotate the heavy platform and it would be difficult to achieve that with just a motor alone

Comment: Correct. You will need encoders too. However, I think you underestimate the weight. 100kg will almost certainly not be even half the mass that must be moved.

Comment: Some of us are 120kg without anything else. So re-visit your guess of the total mass.

Comment: If this is for you, then go ahead. If you are thinking of letting anyone else use it then you have a machine that can (and probably will) squash limbs. Your motor capacities will be set by your acceleration targets for the platform, and then the kinematics and inertia of each arm.

Comment: If you search for FAA-approved flight simulators for sale you get an idea of the price range ($ 100k+ to $1 million US dollars) and a measure of controls sophistication, such as the input of air density, and wind shear. trust reversal feedback.

Comment: You can't simulate the thrust of a fighter jet for any reasonable durations of time with motors.  That requires acceleration and acceleration over time results in a lot of distance...you're better off just messing with the images and forgetting about simulating orientation or acceleration because you can't do it correctly anyway